# Regular Expression to match a string of numbers including special characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match a string of numbers, but this string can contain some special characters such as , `.`, `-`, `+`. This is required to be able to detect phone numbers in a text and remove them.

I used the expression

```
/^(.*)([\d\(\)\-\_\.\+\ ]{10,30})(.*)$/im
```

to do that but this matches strings that contains only 10 spaces as well.

How can I edit this expression so that I can ensure that it contains at least 10 digits ?

Comment: But the beginning and ending `(.*)` will match _any_ character. Could you post an input sample of what you have exactly and what you need to match?

Comment: it depends upon whether the tool, application, or laguage you have running the regex supports lookaround - please add a tag representing that

Comment: see my answer for one that should be supported by most flavors of regex these days - not POSIX, though - I think you'd have to expand all the character classes, but since you're using `\d` in your question, that's probably N/A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
([-()_.+ ]*\d[-()_.+ ]*){10,}
```

This will match a digits surrounded by any number of special characters, which must be repeated at least 10 times.

Comment: This regular expression matches also strings with letters. It should only match string with numbers and special characters

Comment: @HaniGoc It will only match digits and those special characters that were specified. It will match the pattern in a larger portion of text, e.g. From the string, `"Phone: (123) 456-7890"` it will match `": (123) 456-7890"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
/^(?=.*?\d{10,})(.*?)([-\d()_.+\s]{10,30})(.*)$/im
```

Comment: This will only match a string that *contains* 10 contiguous digits. I don't think this is what OP wants. Phone numbers are rarely written that way. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers

Comment: @p.s.w.g Question has been pretty vague and only when you commented I learned about this phone # requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this in the past:

```
/1?[2-9]\D*\d\D*\d[^2-9]*[2-9](\D*\d[^02-9]*[02-9]|[^02-9]*[02-9]\D*\d)\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d/
```

It's probably hard to decode for beginners, but it matches 10 (or eleven if they start with a 1) digits, that conform to most (I think all) of the NANP standards, and allow ANY text between the digits

If you want to only allow `.`, `-`. `+`, then you would replace every `\D` with `[.-+]`