# Regular expression for numeric with special characters **Only**

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am looking for a Regular expression to match only **numeric** strings with **special** characters and of size **4+**.
I did a little review on the questions posted in here:

**Testing website:** http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

---

1- [regular expression for numeric and special chacter check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999944/regular-expression-for-numeric-and-special-chacter-check)

**Solution:** `^((?!.*?\d)(?!.*?[^\w\s]).)+$`

I tried this regular expression on:

- 155-555: No match (wrong)
- 155555: No match (wrong)

---

2- [Regular Expression to match a string of numbers including special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121301/regular-expression-to-match-a-string-of-numbers-including-special-characters)

**Solution:** `([-()_.+ ]*\d[-()_.+ ]*){4,}`

- 155-555: match (correct)
- 155555: match (correct)
- 155-555aaa: match (wrong)

This regular expressions matched the previous strings. But there is an error. The third string **155-555aaa** contains alphabet letters and not special characters. We should have no match for **155-555aaa** since **a** is not a special character. How can I modify this regular expression to only match numeric string with special characters.
The numeric string can be of any form:

**example:** 24332-2432@2342-1234

---

**Special Characters** : [&~#"{'[(|-`_\ç^à@)]}=}^¨$$*%ù]

**numeric** = digits

Comment: What's a "special character"? Is ぷ special?

Comment: ok Special Characters: [&~#"{'[(|-`_\ç^à@)]}=}^¨$$*%ù]

Comment: How about How about: `[^a-zA-Z]{4,}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just match anything that *isn't* `[a-zA-Z]` (with a length of 4 or more):

```
^[^a-z\s]{4,}$
```

[Here is a test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%5B%5Ea-z%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24&input=155-555%0A24332-2432%402342-1234%0A155555%0A155-555aaa) on RegexPal.

Comment: Yes, hence `[^a-z]` as opposed to `[a-z]`

Comment: He negates all letters, but also matches the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string, which is how he prevents "155-555aaa" from being a match.

Comment: Note that spaces will also match this negation, so (`3 4 5 6 7 8`) is a match, as are (`1     2`) and even just a bunch of spaces.

Comment: @Dane thanks for the heads up. I've edited my answer so the regex now rejects whitespace

Answer (score 1):

With the update special characters=``` [&~#"{'[(|-``_\ç^à@)]}=}^¨$*%ù] ``` the class for "special or digit" becomes just ``` [0-9&~#"{'[(|-``_\ç^à@)]}=}^¨$*%ù] ``` and the full regex becomes 
``` ^[0-9&~#"{'[(|-``_\ç^à@)]}=}^¨$*%ù]{4,}$ ```.

But it's rather suspicious that ù is special and ú isn't.